# Using the same soil In containers with fertiliser every year

Tags: tomatoes, container-gardening

I want to use the same soil I bought last year for tomatoes. It is covered in plastic and in a very sunny spot (so I hope to kill off all the fungus that might be lurking), and I am mostly wondering about whether they will grow well if I dissolve egg shells for calcium, add Epsom salts, and use normal tomato fertiliser regularly?

Or is replacing every necessary nutrient (I'm not sure just those are all the necessary nutrients!) really not possible artificially?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soil_steam_sterilization

Comment: Not sure i completely understand the question, but you don't want fertilised soil for little plants. And maybe, there are still some unwanted things in the soil, a thong you never can rule out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always best for tomatoes, peppers, egg plant, and potatoes, to rotate them in a vegetable garden from year to year. This applies to pots. You can reuse the soil from last year for a different crop/flower, but do NOT put tomatoes back into the same pot each year. I also reuse soil in pots, but for flowers not vegetables. When I do this, I unpot the soil, mix it with either fresh soil or compost, and then put it back. For fertilizer, I use a product called Osmocote, which is time-released throughout the summer. No need for Epsom salts or egg shells (too much calcium is bad for the plants)